# Simple CSS fixed header

Tags: css, header

What is the easiest way to make the following page header a fixed header? http://presentationtube.com/header.php
Should I move the Menu elements in the header?

Comment: #templatemo_header_wrapper{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 999999;
}

#templatemo_banner_wrapper{
margin-top: 5%;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way:

```
#templatemeo_header_wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    height: 70px;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to use z-index unless there are other elements in your document that use it. Especially if your document is structured well. And z-index:999999 is really frowned upon.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, but I found z-index with a greater stack order is very important to bring the header in front of the page elements, as suggested by Oussama ELGOUMRI. The only problem was that part of the page is shifted up behind the header. I moved the page down by increasing the margin: margin-top: 65px;

Comment: Now it works fine with z-index: 9999 and here is the test page
http://presentationtube.com/index_eng_fixed.php
and the permanent page if not found is available at:
http://presentationtube.com

Comment: Set z-index to 1 and it works. You will need to set a padding on any content that appears below the header. The padding should match the height of the header. Ideally put everything below the header in a single wrapper div and give that padding-top:65px (or whatever the header height is).

Answer (score 1):

```
#templatemo_header_wrapper {   
 top: 0px; position: fixed
 }
```

fixed at top 0

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
#templatemo_header_wrapper {
     position:fixed;
}
```

If that is not correct you will need to elaborate on your question.

**EDIT**

I would like to expand on this. There is extra markup that is not needed.

The current css looks like this:

```
#templatemo_header_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #19446a url(images/templatemo_header_bg_65_ora.jpg) repeat-x;
}
```

As the body is already set at margin:0 and padding:0 you do not need to specify top and left coordinates for the #templatemo_header_wrapper. So to avoid writing additional css you can change the element to this:

```
#templatemo_header_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  background: #19446a url(images/templatemo_header_bg_65_ora.jpg) repeat-x;
  position: fixed;
}
```

I've removed the margin property as this does not apply here. You can also dispense with the height property. Sometimes it is useful to set height for a fixed position element. But as you have child elements that also have height specified (and/or padding margins) this will naturally add height to the parent container as needed.

So the final markup could look like this:

```
#templatemo_header_wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: #19446a url(images/templatemo_header_bg_65_ora.jpg) repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: Thank you lharby, would you please see my comment to Oussama ELGOUMRI (solved) and comment?

Comment: Done lharby, thank you, now works at http://presentationtube.com/index_eng_fixed.php