# How to code a scrolling frame in css

Tags: html, css

Using the page in the link below as an example, I am trying to figure out how to code the page so the header stays static, and only the information in the body would scroll when a user scrolls up and down, rather then the whole page however I cannot figure it out. I understand it can be done with frames however I was wanting to do it without it.

example page:
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-full-page.htm

=========================

Thank you. Editing it I'm sure I'm just missing something simple I just cannot figure out what to change to the fixed code. Here is the header code I am using.

```
/* Header styles */
#header {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
#header {
    border-bottom:1px solid #04B45F;
}
#header p,
#header h1,
#header h2 {
    padding:.4em 15px 0 15px;
    margin:0;
}
#header ul {
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    list-style:none;
    margin:10px 0 0 0;
    padding:0;
}
#header ul li {
    display:inline;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#header ul li a {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin:0 0 0 1px;
    padding:3px 10px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#eee;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    position:relative;
    left:15px;
    line-height:1.3em;
}
#header ul li a:hover {
    background:#369;
    color:#fff;
}
#header ul li a.active,
#header ul li a.active:hover {
    color:#000;
    background:#fff;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#header ul li a span {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple CSS fixed header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200440/simple-css-fixed-header)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need iframe, use CSS `position: fixed` instead, example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/exuhyf9a/

Comment: thank you just trying to figure out which part to change, added my coding up top.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to create a header div (say, `width:100%; height:50px;`), then create a container div with `height:calc(100vh - 50px); overflow:scroll` - and put everything else in the container.  The container will automatically scale to the screen height of your device (less the top 50px, reserved for the header), and any content longer than its height will scroll, leaving the header displayed at the top. See an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/exuhyf9a/1/) - using an external container to simulate of the viewport.