# HTML div bg color and content

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to put a background picture inside my website and since my div class "header" is not working properly. Here is the code. Can anyone explain why is that so? The div header and img circular should be stuck on top of the page when scrolling down the website. edit: additional closing tag on body was causing all the fuzz.

```css
 body {
      background-color: #ffffcc;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  }
  .header {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #006600;
    margin-top: -1.5%;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
  }
  .img-circular {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url(../images/stareLogo.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 45%;
    margin-right: 45%;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
  }
  .main {
    clear: both;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="Roto-car topowy szczeciński warsztat samochodowy">
  <meta name="keywords" content="warsztat,szczecin,serwis,samochód,samochodowy,car,repair,fix,naprawa,samochodu,auto">
  <meta name="author" content="Dominik Leszczenko">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
  <title>Roto-car - Szczeciński warsztat samochodowy</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="img-circular"></div>
  </header>
  <div class="main">
    <h1>Roto-car</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>Szczeciński warsztat samochodowy</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you aware that in the code you posted, there is no `<style></style>` wrapping for the css content and you are not loading any stylesheets in your head by using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">` ?

Comment: What do you mean with _my website and since my div class "header" is not working properly._?

Comment: Their is a extra close tag at the end of body in your style

Comment: Do you just want fixed header?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple CSS fixed header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200440/simple-css-fixed-header)

Comment: I will go through the books of html once again. i must've misunderstood something with how the css works. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Karthik N. I havnt seen additional closing tag. That caused all the fuzz. Sorry and thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to achieve this kind of solution:

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffffcc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #006600;
  overflow: auto;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
.img-circular {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/black-icon-social-media/256/099280-blinklist-logo.png);
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 15px 0 0 -35px;
  background-color: white;
}
.main {
  background-color: red;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="Roto-car topowy szczeciński warsztat samochodowy">
  <meta name="keywords" content="warsztat,szczecin,serwis,samochód,samochodowy,car,repair,fix,naprawa,samochodu,auto">
  <meta name="author" content="Dominik Leszczenko">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
  <title>Roto-car - Szczeciński warsztat samochodowy</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="img-circular"></div>
  </header>
  <div class="main">
    <h1>Roto-car</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the header min-height and give background color for it then you will see the header. In style you should give **header**  not ***.header***